# Avoiding NULL records on this LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below works - EXCEPT - it is returning NULL values for vehicle_id. I do not want any records that have NULL for vehicle_id.

Since vehicle_id is tied to fund_series, this is complicated to me.

When I had the vehicle_id conditions underneath the WHERE, the query was not working. Any SQL geniuses that can help?

I put the MIN() aggregate functions in there just so I could get the GROUP BY to work.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
           MIN(ml.pretty_file_name),
           ml.filename,
           MIN(ml.issued_date),
           MIN(mr.rule_name),
           MIN(mlob.line_of_business_name),
           MIN(mt.media_type_name),
           MAX(v.vehicle_name) 
   FROM Media_Live ml
       JOIN Media_Type mt
           ON mt.media_type_id = ml.media_type_id
       JOIN Media_Rule mr
           ON mr.rule_id = ml.rule_id
       JOIN Media_Line_Of_Business mlob 
           ON mlob.line_of_business_id = ml.line_of_business_id 
       LEFT JOIN Fund_Class_Media fcm
           ON fcm.media_id=ml.media_id
       LEFT JOIN Fund_Class_Live fc
           ON fc.fund_class_id = fcm.fund_class_id
       LEFT JOIN Fund_Series fs
           ON fs.fund_series_id = fc.fund_series_id
       LEFT JOIN Vehicle AS v
           ON v.vehicle_id=fs.vehicle_id AND /*THIS IS WHERE IM GETTING NULLS*/
           ( 
           v.vehicle_id = 1
           OR v.vehicle_id = 2
           OR v.vehicle_id = 5
           )
       LEFT JOIN Media_Media_Tag AS mmt ON mmt.media_id=ml.media_id
       LEFT JOIN Media_Tag AS mtag ON mtag.tag_id=mmt.tag_id
   WHERE
       (/*people can search with terms for fc*/
        --fc.fund_class_id LIKE '%'+replace(?,' ','%')+'%' 
       )
       ( 
           mt.media_type_id = 33
           OR mt.media_type_id = 1
           OR mt.media_type_id = 12
       )
       AND
       (
           mr.rule_id = 3
           OR mr.rule_id = 9
       )
       AND
       (
           mtag.tag_name != 'exclude_web_lit_center'
       )
   GROUP BY ml.filename
```

Comment: So why don't you use an `INNER JOIN` there instead?

Comment: You could add `v.Vehicl_Id IS NOT NULL` to the `WHERE` clause and filter the rows without vehicle ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a left join does, allow nulls.  Just take out the left join part making it an inner join.

```
JOIN Vehicle AS v ON v.vehicle_id=fs.vehicle_id AND v.vehicle_id IN (1,2,5)
```

You cold also do this, but I don't see why you would:

```
LEFT JOIN Vehicle AS v ON v.vehicle_id=fs.vehicle_id AND ISNULL(v.vehicle_id,0) IN (1,2,5)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the `WHERE` clause, add:

```
AND v.Vehicl_Id IS NOT NULL
```

That should do it.